# Why is my code not making the entire array print in sequential order

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

an array is entered:

```
ary[] = [11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 11 12 13 14 -1]    (the negative one signifies that it is the end of the array)
```

a size is entered:

```
size = 34
```

I need this array to be rearranged so that it is in sequential order. Below is my code:

```
int x;
int numpasses;
int temp;

for(numpasses = 1; numpasses < size; numpasses++)
{
  for(x = 0; x < size - numpasses; x++)
  {
    if(ary[x] > ary[x + 1] && ary[x] != ary[size - 1])
     {
       temp = ary[x];
       ary[x] = ary[x + 1];  //THIS PORTION SWITHCHES TWO ADJECENT VALUES TO MAKE ARRAY SEQUENTIAL 
       ary[x + 1] = temp;
     }
   }
   int a;
   for(a = 0; a < size; a++)
   {
     printf("%d  ", ary[a]);
   }
 }
```

This prints the numbers as follows:

11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 20 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 11 12 13 14

Comment: If you think `size` and `SIZE` may have something to do with this, you'd likely be on to something.

Comment: @WhozCraig just a typo, all the variables correspond

Comment: Are you told to use any specific sorting and searching algorithm?

Comment: I am supposed to be using bubble sorting if that's what you're asking

Comment: When I was a lad we had to use `printf` to figure out what our algorithms were up to when something went wrong. If things got really hairy we'd be forced to use <gasp> a debugger. Seems like debugging code is a lost art these days.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to type the print loop, I did actually do that and I am still a lad. haha

Comment: The other old fashioned debug trick is: Draw say 5 squares on a sheet of paper. Put a number in each. This is your array. Now manually walk through what you've written (not what you think you've written) - you can find a lot of stuff really quickly this way...

Comment: @john3136 I did that too, it works for smaller arrays (size of 9) but it does not work for this larger one.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the line

```
     if(ary[x] > ary[x + 1] && ary[x] != ary[size - 1])
```

by

```
     if(ary[x] > ary[x + 1] )
```

worked fine for me.

I'll let you figure out why.

**PS.**

Please add

```
  printf("\n");
```

after printing the array. It makes seeing the result at the end of the outer loop a little bit clearer.